# How do I change TextView font style in a Home screen widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How do I change the font style in a TextView in a Home screen widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean in runtime, a simple way is:

Text Size

```
yourRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.textview, "setTextSize", 30);
```

Text Color

```
yourRemoteView.setInt(R.id.textview, "setTextColor", Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

First, define text styles in `values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
        ....
    </style>
    <style name="WidgetEntryTitle" parent="style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="WidgetEntryDate" parent="style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, use the styles in `mywidget_layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <TextView style="@style/WidgetEntryTitle"
        ... />

    <TextView style="@style/WidgetEntryDate"
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```